# What is the equivalent standard function of the "AfxIsValidAddress" function?

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc, platform-independent, afx

I was using an MFC-project, that shall be proted in a platform-independent environment, using std-function instead of MFC/AFX.

For example: instead CString the std::string, instead CMutex the std::mutex will be used.

What is the platform-independet, C++11 std::-equivalent of the MFC function "AfxIsValidAddress"?

Comment: In standard C++ there are no equivalent to `AfxIsValidAddress`. And why do you need it anyway? What problem is it supposed to solve? In non-debug builds it's just a plain null-pointer check.

Comment: If I check the implementation, then I see more checks at once, inside this function. Are those all inactive in non-debug builds or what?

Comment: If you need to use `AfxIsValidAddress`, your code has a bug. Fix the bug, forget about the broken MFC implementation (calling into a broken Windows API). The platform-independent, C++11 `std::`-equivalent is to not need it. If you do, you're in UB land, and no guarantees hold at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not something similar to `AfxIsValidAddress()` in the standard library and it appears that the function doesn't actually do that much validation anyway.

See [AfxIsValidAddress (and Others) Don’t Work as Advertised](https://ofekshilon.com/2011/01/31/afxisvalidaddress-et-al-dont-work-as-advertised/) which says the function ends up just doing a check against NULL. It also has this to say about the family of valid address check functions:

> There are several Win32 API similar in functionality: `IsBadWritePtr`,
>   `IsBadHugeWritePtr`, `IsBadReadPtr`, `IsBadHugeReadPtr`, `IsBadCodePtr`,
>   `IsBadStringPtr`. It has been known since at least 2004 that these
>   functions are broken beyond repair and should never be used. The
>   almighty Raymond Chen and Larry Osterman both discuss the reasons in
>   detail, so just a short rehash: IsBad*Ptr all work by accessing the
>   tested address and catching any thrown exceptions. Problem is that a
>   certain few of these access violations (namely, those on stack guard
>   pages) should never be caught – the OS uses them to properly enlarge
>   thread stacks.

I think it is better to just follow standard C++ procedures to check that a pointer is not a `nullptr` or better yet to limit the use of pointers as much as possible.